# Problemas con la declaracion de atributos y métodos en Python

Tags: python-3.x, diseño-de-clases, atributos

Tengo una duda con el siguiente código. Se trata de un programa en Python de Listas Ligadas Simples. El problema es que no se exactamente como es que se declararon algunos atributos como
**aux.sig** en el metodo **recorrido(self)** o **nodo.sig** en el metodo **insertar_inicio(self)** ambos de la clase ListaSimple. Por ejemplo, en el metodo insertar_inicio(self), la primera condicional if se cumple si el primer nodo de la lista está vacio, siendo reemplazado el valor del atributo **self.inicio** por el valor del argumento **nodo**. Si no se cumple, es decir, que si hay algun nodo en la lista, **nodo.sig** es igual al inicio de la lista (**self.inicio**). Mi duda es esa, de donde proviene lo que se encuentra declarado después del punto en **nodo.sig**, es decir **.sig** ya que por lo visto **sig** es un atributo de la clase **Nodo** y no está declarado en la clase **ListaLigada**

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, dato):
        self.dato = dato
        self.sig = None

class ListaSimple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inicio = None

    def insertar_inicio(self, nodo):
        if self.inicio is None:
            self.inicio = nodo
        else:
            nodo.sig = self.inicio
            self.inicio = nodo

    def insertar_final(self, nodo):
        if self.inicio is None:
            self.inicio = nodo
        else:
            aux = self.inicio
            while aux.sig is not None:
                aux = aux.sig
            aux.sig = nodo

    def borrar_final(self):
        if self.inicio is not None:
            if self.inicio.sig is None:
                self.inicio = None
            else:
                aux = self.inicio
                aux2 = self.inicio
                while aux.sig is not None:
                    aux2 = aux
                    aux = aux.sig
                aux2.sig = None
                aux = None

    def ordenar(self):
        if self.inicio is not None:
            aux = self.inicio
            while aux.sig is not None:
                aux2 = aux.sig
                while aux2 is not None:
                    if aux.dato > aux2.dato:
                        temp = aux.dato
                        aux.dato = aux2.dato
                        aux2.dato = temp
                    aux2 = aux2.sig
                aux = aux.sig

    def recorrido(self):
        if self.inicio is None:
            print('Lista vacía...')
        else:
            aux = self.inicio
            while aux is not None:
                print(aux.dato, end=' ')
                aux = aux.sig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opcion = 1
    lista = ListaSimple()
    while opcion != 0:
        lista.recorrido()
        print('\n1. Insertar Inicio')
        print('2. Borrado Inicio')
        print('3. Insertar Final')
        print('4. Ordenar elementos')
        print('6. Borrar final')
        print('8. Borrar dato especifico')
        print('0. Salir')
        opcion = int(input('Opcion: '))
        if opcion != 0:
            if opcion == 1:
                dato = int(input('Dato: '))
                lista.insertar_inicio(Nodo(dato))
            elif opcion == 2:
                lista.borrar_inicio()
            elif opcion == 3:
                dato = int(input('Dato: '))
                lista.insertar_final(Nodo(dato))
            elif opcion == 4:
                lista.ordenar()
            elif opcion == 6:
                lista.borrar_final()
            elif opcion == 7:
                dato = int(input('Dato: '))
                encontrado, otro = lista.buscar_nodo(dato)
                if encontrado is None:
                    print('Dato no esta en la lista')
                else:
                    print('El dato esta en la lista')
            elif opcion == 8:
                dato = int(input('Dato: '))
                lista.borrar_nodo(dato)
```

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado, los atributos que mencionas no están declarados en la clase `ListaSimple`, pero si observas detenidamente verás que la clase `ListaSimple`, de cierto modo, espera que los argumentos que generalmente llama como nodo, sean de hecho, objetos de la clase Nodo.

Por ese motivo verás que en las llamadas en lugar de pasar por parámetro el dato

```
# Incorrecto
lista.insertar_inicio(dato)
lista.insertar_final(dato)
```

pasa un objeto de tipo `Nodo`

```
# Correcto
lista.insertar_inicio(Nodo(dato))
lista.insertar_final(Nodo(dato))
```

Los cuales sí tienen la propiedad `sig`, que (creo) es la pregunta que haces.

Luego cuando se asigna a `self.inicio = nodo`, en la clase de la lista tendrás referencia en `self.inicio` a un objeto `nodo`, el cual tiene la propiedad `sig`